# Stripe-Vue payment POST 500 uncaught in promise

Tags: laravel, vue.js, stripe-payments

I think I messed something up with the csrf_field() but I did push the X-CSRF-TOKEN... I had a 419 error before but brought myself more into trouble...

**The error**
- POST /betaling 500 
- Uncaught (in promise) Response {url: "/betaling", ok: false, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", headers: Headers

**Header**

```
<script>
var Cityofcompanies = {
    csrfToken: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    stripeKey: "{{ config('services.stripe.key') }}"
};
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post('betaling', 'PaymentController@store')->name('payment');
```

**App.js**

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');


Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => { 
    request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Cityofcompanies.csrfToken); 
    next(); 
});

Vue.component('CheckoutForm', 
require('./components/CheckoutForm.vue'));
```

**CheckoutForm.vue**

```
<template>
    <form action="/betaling" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" v-model="stripeToken">
        <input type="hidden" name="stripeEmail" v-model="stripeEmail">
        <button type="submit" @click.prevent="buy">Abonneer</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                stripeEmail: '',
                stripeToken: ''
            };

        },

        created() {
            this.stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
                key: Cityofcompanies.stripeKey,
                image:"https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png",
                locale: "auto",
                currency: "eur",
                token: (token) => {
                    this.stripeToken = token.id;
                    this.stripeEmail = token.email;

                    this.$http.post('/betaling', this.$data);
                        //.then(response => alert('Bedankt voor het abonneren!'));
                }
            });
        },

        methods: {
            buy() {
                this.stripe.open({
                    name: "Abonneer voor 1 jaar",
                    description: "Professional Version",
                    amount: 5000,
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Show.blade.php**

```
<div id="checkout">
    <checkout-form></checkout-form>
</div>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        const app = new Vue({
            el: '#checkout'
        });
    }
    </script>
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at the logs for the `/betaling` endpoint to see what the error might be here.